# Wordpress multisite и пути к стилям в режиме подкаталогов

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-multisite

Настраиваю на только что установленном WP мультисайт по [инструкции](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8).
Сначала добавляю в конфиг константу `define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);`
Далее следую инструкциям в админ-панели на экране установок сети, выбрав режим **подкаталогов**:
В .htaccess заменяю правила WordPress на следующие:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

В конфиг добавляю константы:

```
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'multisites');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
```

Создаю сайт 'test' с темой оформления **Twenty Twenty**, перехожу на его главную страницу и вижу, что стили накрылись тазиком. Смотрю как они подключены:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='dashicons-css'  href='http://multisites/test/wp-includes/css/dashicons.min.css?ver=5.3.2' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='admin-bar-css'  href='http://multisites/test/wp-includes/css/admin-bar.min.css?ver=5.3.2' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='wp-block-library-css'  href='http://multisites/test/wp-includes/css/dist/block-library/style.min.css?ver=5.3.2' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='twentytwenty-style-css'  href='http://multisites/test/wp-content/themes/twentytwenty/style.css?ver=1.1' media='all' />
```

Та же беда со скриптами.
Та же беда в админке созданного сайта:

```
<script src='http://multisites/test/wp-includes/js/dist/dom-ready.min.js?ver=2.5.1'></script>
<script src='http://multisites/test/wp-includes/js/dist/a11y.min.js?ver=2.5.1'></script>
```

Часть путей содержит подкаталог, которого на самом деле нет. Не могу понять что я упускаю, почему WP не возвращает пути вида `http://multisites/wp-content/themes/twentytwenty/style.css` или `http://multisites/wp-includes/js/dist/dom-ready.min.js`?

Кто-нибудь сталкивался с такой проблемой? Как решали?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем проблема была в том, что nginx настроен на отдачу статики. В моём случае пришлось закомментировать вот эти строки в настройках чтобы всё заработало как надо:

```
location ~* ^.+\.(?:css(\.map)?|js(\.map)?|jpe?g|png|gif|ico|cur|heic|webp|tiff?|mp3|m4a|aac|ogg|midi?|wav|mp4|mov|webm|mpe?g|avi|ogv|flv|wmv|svgz?|ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff2?)$ {
        expires 1d;
        access_log off;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Постоянные ссылки по-прежнему будут работать, хотя на основном блоге (т.е. на первом из созданных) к адресам будет добавлен префикс blog, и они примут вид domain.com/blog/YYYY/MM/POSTNAME

Это сделано, чтобы предотвратить конфликты между страницами и новыми сайтами в режиме подкаталогов. На текущий момент нет простого способа это изменить, поскольку в этом случае WordPress не сможет автоматически разрешать конфликты между основным и дочерними сайтами. Это будет исправлено в одной из следующих версий WordPress.

https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8#.D0.9F.D0.B5.D1.80.D0.B5.D0.B4_.D0.BD.D0.B0.D1.87.D0.B0.D0.BB.D0.BE.D0.BC

Вроде там надо играться с путями для подключения стилей и скриптов.